# Why hasn't "still image camera matching" technology been used for tracking moving shots?

Tags: tracking

Camera Matching adjusts a camera viewpoint so that the perspective in a background image matches the perspective of the digital world (Rotation and location of a camera in a 3D software). This allows you to place 3D objects as if they were part of the background image.

For example ,there exists a software called fSpy, that lets you place vanishing points, representing each of the axis's. fSpy will then generate camera data that you can export to your project, as seen on the right of the video. I'm sure the short video on their website, https://fspy.io/ can demonstrate much better than I can explain in words here, or this image here:
[image]

So my question is why hasn't this kind of software been applied to moving video? You can track the points, and then you only have to track 8 points, versus the many you would have to track using standard motion tracking. It also seems to be much more accurate.

Has this been done before, is there a reason why it hasn't been done before, or have I just came up with a groundbreaking idea?

Comment: After watching the video, I'm not sure I understand what the purpose is and what you are asking. You might want to add a screenshot here as the video doesn't add much information. The homepage of the software [fspy.io](https://fspy.io) might give a hint.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will be sure to edit the question with extra details to make more sense. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, After Effects (and other compositing apps) already has Camera tracking built in. You track a piece of footage, it solves for the camera movement, and creates a virtual camera. Then any 3D layers will look as though they are in the 3D world of the shot. https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/tracking-3d-camera-movement.html

Answer (score 1):

You're describing augmented reality.

Try something like Carrot Weather's AR Mode or Memoji?

The answer to your question is "Many vendors have implemented 'Augmented Reality' or AR, which works similarly to fSpy.

Comment: I don't think so. Augmented reality is just regular tracking but in real time. It uses the same standard system of lots of trackers, just really fast, in real time. I don't think It uses the perspective system as I described. However if I am wrong does such a software exist for creating camera movement as I described?

Comment: Yes, trackers have existed for some time. They were very expensive, but costs are coming down rapidly.